# Send mouse coordinates etc to server

Tags: java, networking

Let's say I want to send my mouse coordinates alongside with other stuff to the server. What would be the best way to do that? My idea was to create an object and attach data to it and sent it. I've posted my try as u can see: (It does not work.) Is this a good way to do it? What am I doing wrong? etc. If it's not a good idea, how should I do it instead?

**Client code**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket clientSocket = null;
        ObjectOutputStream out = null;
        ObjectInputStream in = null;

        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket("My ip", 4441);
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream()); // Stuff to send to server
            in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()); // Stuff server sends

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Unknown host");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        while (true) {
            out.writeByte(1);
            out.writeObject(new CustomObject());
            out.flush();
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomObject**

```
public class CustomObject {

    public int mouseX, mouseY;

    public CustomObject() {
        this.mouseX = 10;
        this.mouseY = 16;
    }
}
```

**Server**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4441);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connected");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Accept failed.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream()); 

        CustomObject go;
        while (true) {      
            go = (CustomObject) in.readObject();
            System.out.println( go.mouseX );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `CustomObject` should implement `Serializable` if you want to send it thought a network.

Comment: @boxed__l Thanks. Do I need to do more to it than implementing it?

Comment: its a marker interface, so no nothing more than `implements serializable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say how it doesn't work, but what is immediately detectable is that you don't read the same thing as what you write:

What you write:

```
while (true) {
    out.writeByte(1);
    out.writeObject(new CustomObject());
    out.flush();
}
```

What you read:

```
while (true) {      
    go = (CustomObject) in.readObject();
    System.out.println( go.mouseX );
}
```

So, stop sending this unused byte, and it will probably work better.

Oh, and as noted in the comment by @bowed__l, the CustomObject must implement java.io.Serializable to be serializable.

If you have other problems, the post the stack trace of the exception you get. And if you don't get any, then explain precisely what happens.

Comment: Thanks it works now! But is this the "right" way to send mouse coordinates?

Comment: It's an acceptable way, yes. If that's the only thing to send, you could simply write two integers using a DataOutputStream, and read these two integers using a DataInputStream. Serializing an object has a cost, in terms of time and bandwidth. But premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Ok thanks. When I stop the client program I get "Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error" for this: out.writeObject(new CustomObject()); Any idea why?

Comment: You mean, when you stop the server program, right? Well, obviously you get an exception since the srever isn't there to read what you write anymore. That's the same thing as when you phone someone and he hangs up in the middle of the conversation: your phone starts beeping to tell you that the receiver hung up.